# Solutions of $2x\sqrt{1-x^2} \geq 1$ and $2x\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq 1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have to solve the following inequalities, but I'm a bit confused by the presence of the square root. What is the *correct* way to get rid of it and solve the problem?

$$2x\sqrt{1-x^2} \geq 1$$ and $$2x\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq 1$$

Note that I need to solve the inequalities *separately*, not simultaneously.

Comment: First of all, realize that $-1 \leq x \leq 1$. Any other values for $x$ give us a negative value in the radicand.

Comment: @amWhy Yes, this is clear. I don't know how to handle the square root though.

Comment: Square root (on its typically defined domain) is 1-1. So $x\leq y \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{x} \leq \sqrt{y}$...

Comment: The square root value is going to be $\geq 0, \leq 1$, so positive. Consider both positive and negative values of $x$ (which will determine the sign of the left\hand side. Clearly $x\geq 0$ in the first (hence lhs +). In the second case, x can be negative.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Be careful: $-\sqrt x \leq -\sqrt y \rightarrow x\geq y$. $x \in [-1, 1] \implies 2x \in [-2, 2]$, hence the left-hand side can be negative (in the second case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First approach: Use substitution $x=\cos(t)$ to prove that the second inequality holds true for all admissible values of $x$.

Second approach: Use standard inequality $2ab\leq a^2+b^2$ with $a=x$, $b=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ to show the same. Note that equality is attained only if $a=b$.

Comment: This doesn't help

Comment: Refresh your trigonometry then.

Comment: plotting can help focus your derivations: [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2x*sqrt%281-x%5E2%29+for+x%3D-1+to+1)

Comment: @amWhy Anyway, something more explicit (and without trigonometric functions) would be helpful.

Comment: @user62029 I'm sure Norbert *is* trying to be helpful. You should state your requirements and "demands" within your posts. It's not our job to try to mind-read.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this without trig, just using quadratic equation.  first observe that $$ f(x) = 2x\sqrt{1-x^2},\, -1 \le x \le 1$$ is an odd function. therefore it is enough to consider the case $0 \le x \le 1.$ let us find out more about the range of $f.$ we can turn $$y = 2x\sqrt{1-x^2} \ge 0 $$ into the quadratic equation for $u = x^2$ by squaring. we get $$ y^2 = 4x^2 (1-x^2) \to 4u^2 - 4u+y^2 = 0.$$ we need $y$ so that $u \ge 0.$ first we need the discriminant, $$16 - 16y^2 \ge 0.$$ which implies $-1 \le y \le 1$ because $y \ge 0 \text{ for } x \ge 0,$  we have $$0 \le y \le 1. $$

we will solve $y = 1$ for $x.$ by the quadratic formula $x = -\frac{b}{2a}$ when discriminant is zero gives $$u = \frac{4}{2 \times 4} = \frac12, x = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}.$$

we have $$ max\{2x\sqrt{1-x^2} \colon  0 \le x \le 1\} = f(1/\sqrt 2) = 1$$

Comment: Could you solve it in a simpler way, please?

Comment: @user62029, this is the simplest, without any trig, only using the basic stuff about quadratic that i can come up with to find the maximum of $2x\sqrt{1-x^2}.$

Answer (score -1):

Hint 2: $y=x^2$ and consider:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%281-y%29+for+y%3D0+to+1